# Smart Case sensitivity Search in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

Is there a smart case sensitivity search in PyCharm?

In the past I used an editor which did case insensitive search if I used lower case.

As soon as I used the first upper case character the search was case sensitive.

I liked this.

Can I enable this in PyCharm?

BTW: of course I know that I can enable case sensitive search in PyCharm. This question is about the "smartness" of switching to case sensitive search.

Comment: No, there is no option in PyCharm to enable this behavior.

Answer (score 3):

As it seems that this is [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49528885/smart-case-sensitivity-search-in-pycharm#comment86065255_49528885), you could always register your previous editor as an [external tool](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-third-party-tools.html) in PyCharm, and add a keyboard shortcut for quick smart case-sensitive searches.

Sometimes, the external editor makes it easier to do simple edits. PyCharm should update as soon as you save the file in the external editor.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is No.

Python is mostly typed in lower case. Simple thing is to just click `Alt+C` which check marks **Match Case** as you are aware.

So I think most editors do not have the smart search you are mentioning intentionally so that they want user to explicitly control what they are searching.

You might want to look at `search.py` at *C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd_attach_to_process\winappdbg\search.py* and fiddle with it a little and check if you can get this `smartsearch` feature.